# Event handler not being delegated to parent element

Tags: javascript, event-handling, delegates

Creating event listeners for a lot of elements can slow down a page and use a lot of memory. So I’ve been trying to place my event handler on a containing element and use the event object’s target property to find which of its children the event happened on. This would give better performance and if items were to be removed or added the page will still work the same. It’s all very well in theory but in practise I can’t get  my code to do what’s it’s expected to be doing.

What’s more the console is throwing: Uncaught TypeError: “Cannot read property 'target' of undefined at getTarget (index.js:3) at removeItem (index.js:8) at index.js:19”. It seems to be pointing to the  parameter “e”, which has first been passed into the “getTarget” function. I don’t know what to make of the error thrown by the console. I was under the impression that without doing anything a reference to the event object was automatically passed and then we just had to name it - programmers often give the name “e”.

```js
function getTarget(e) {
  return e.target;
}

function removeItem(e) {
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  var target = getTarget(e);
  var parent = target.parentNode;
  parent.removeChild(target);

  target.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    removeItem(e)
  }, false)

}

removeItem()
```

```html
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Practise App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div class="">Monday</div>
      <div class="">Tuesday</div>
      <div class="">Wednesday</div>
      <div class="">Thursday</div>
      <div class="">Friday</div>
      <div class="">Saturday</div>
      <div class="">Sunday</div>
    </div>
    <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote my code. It's now more elegant and efficient in that it uses fewer lines of code. In my previous code I passed an argument to a named function that was called by an event handler. You can't have parentheses after a function name in event listeners, so I used a workaround. The work around in question consist in wrapping the function name in a anonymous function.

That was an unnecessary. I'm now only using an anonymous function, where an argument, namely the event object is passed.

```js
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", function(e){
  var target = e.target;
  var parent = target.parentNode;
  parent.removeChild(target)
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Practise App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div class="">Monday</div>
      <div class="">Tuesday</div>
      <div class="">Wednesday</div>
      <div class="">Thursday</div>
      <div class="">Friday</div>
      <div class="">Saturday</div>
      <div class="">Sunday</div>
    </div>
    <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

now more efficient and elegant in that it uses fewer lines

```js
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", function(e){
  var target = e.target;
  var parent = target.parentNode;
  parent.removeChild(target)
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Practise App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div class="">Monday</div>
      <div class="josue">Tuesday</div>
      <div class="">Wednesday</div>
      <div class="josue">Thursday</div>
      <div class="">Friday</div>
      <div class="josue">Saturday</div>
      <div class="">Sunday</div>
    </div>
    <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```